# Caused by: org.usb4java.LoaderException: Native library not found in classpath /org/usb4java/windows-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dll

Tags: java, usb4java

**System**:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Eclipse Photon

Problem:

Trying to use `usb4java` package in my project to select correct usb port and start moving information through it. I downloaded the package from usb4java.org, unzipped and added it to the references from java build path.

```
import org.usb4java.Context;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;
import org.usb4java.LibUsbException;

 private void initializeLibUsb() {
    int result = LibUsb.init(null);
    if( result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialize libusb.",result);
    }
}
```

This results in the error:

> Caused by: org.usb4java.LoaderException: Native library not found in
>   classpath: /org/usb4java/windows-x86_64/libusb-1.0.dll

Where am I supposed to get the libusb-1.0.dll?

Comment: Does your CLASSPATH include `lib/libusb-1.0-windows-x86_64.jar`?

Comment: `usb4java-1.2.0.jar` was added to the CLASSPATH but `ib/libusb-1.0-windows-x86_64.jar` was not. I added it and the error is now gone.

Comment: Do I have to include all the .jar files that are included in the usb4java-1.2.0.zip package?

Comment: No, only the ones that are needed. E.g. if you're on Windows, you don't need the Linux jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included the file `lib/libusb-1.0-windows-x86_64.jar` in the classpath.